# Keycloak grant token not maintained in express routes

Tags: express, routes, token, keycloak, sql-grant

I'm wanting to use Keycloak to authenticate users and protect my express routes. For the login route, I get back a keycloak-token from the grant manager which I store in keycloak. For now I'm using a `temp` account to login directly:

```
...
let memoryStore = session.MemoryStore;
let kcConfig = {...};
let keycloak = new Keycloak({ store : memoryStore }, kcConfig);

/* Route */
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
     keycloak.grantManager.obtainDirectly('temp', 'temp').then(grant => {
         keycloak.storeGrant(grant, req, res);
     }, error => {
         console.log("ERROR");
     });

     // Send some default info back
     res.send({user: "me", token: "nnn"});
     res.end();
});
```

After doing this, req.session has a 'keycloak-token' property. However, when I then try to navigate to protected routes, e.g.

```
app.use('/app', keycloak.protect(), app);
```

Then that req.session['keycloak-token'] is gone and I'm still redirected to the Keycloak login page. *After* I login there, THEN my token seems to be set and I can access the protected routes as I wish.

Why is the session token from the grant manager in the login route not shared and maintained like the one from the `keycloak.protect()` route protector?

Answer (score 0):

You should install Keycloak middleware as well

```
app.use(keycloak.middleware({
    logout: '/logout',
    admin: '/'
}));
```